# Why peep and pop operations are returning garbage value?

Tags: arrays, c, stack

Here's the code-

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define SIZE 10

struct stack{
    int st[SIZE];
    int top;
};

void init_stack(struct stack *s);
void push(struct stack *s, int item);
int pop(struct stack *s);
void peep(struct stack *s);

void main(){
    int opt, ele;

    struct stack s;
    init_stack(&s);

    label:

    printf("Enter the operation you want to perform: \n 1. Push \n 2. Pop \n 3. Peep \n 4. Exit \n");
    scanf("%d", &opt);

    switch(opt){
        case 1:
        printf("Enter the element you want to push: ");
        scanf("%d", &ele);
        push(&s, ele);
        goto label;

        case 2:
        printf("Popped item: %d\n",pop(&s));
        goto label;

        case 3:
        peep(&s);
        goto label;

        case 4:
        break;

        default:
        printf("Please enter the valid option!");
        goto label;
    }

}

void init_stack(struct stack *s){
    s->top = -1;
}

void push(struct stack *s, int item){
    if(s->top == SIZE -1){
        printf("Stack is full! \n");
    } else {
        s->st[s->top] = item;
        s->top++;
    }
}

int pop(struct stack *s){
    if(s->top == -1){
        printf("Stack is empty! \n");
    } else {
        return s->st[s->top];
        s->top--;
    }
}

void peep(struct stack *s){
    if(s->top == -1){
        printf("Stack is empty! \n");
    } else {
        printf("Top item in the stack: %d \n", s->st[s->top]);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to implement stack using arrays in C. I programmed it without using struct and it worked fine. Our DSA teacher told us to use structure. Now, when I perform push() and pop() operations, they give garbage values. I don't know what I'm doing wrong So please help me, Thank You!

Comment: The `pop` function is wrong, in the `else` part you're doing things in the wrong order. In `peep` you have a similar problem. It's trivial, you're able to find out yourself.

Comment: Tip: Use `0` as the initial count of items. The first `push()` goes to `arr[0]`, then the increment indicates that there's `1` item on the stack... Shift your indexing up by one! Use C's natural 0-9 to index 10 elements... Think "post increment push, pre decrement pop..."

Comment: @Jabberwocky thank you for replying and it works when I change order but why does it work that way? Suppose I'm pushing an element (let's say 4) then value of top will be 0, then if I perform pop operation then i should return s->st[s->top] (where top's value is still 0 and should send stack[0] then top should be decremented by 1, right? Please tell me what I am missing. Thank You

Comment: @dante the order you do things is important. You want to drive to your girl friend and your fuel tank is almost empty. What do you do? 1: fill the tank then drive to your girl friend or 2: drive to your girl friend and then fill the tank. You see the problem?

Comment: @Fe2O3 sorry it still doesn't work(the answer i just deleted), the pop and peep functions are giving the same values, can you please tell me again, what's wrong here?

Comment: I used to think it was peek, but now see this https://www.peepsbrand.com/recipes/easter-push-pop-peeps/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I messed up the order in push() and pop() function, that's how it should be-

```
void push(struct stack *s, int item){
    if(s->top == SIZE -1){
        printf("Stack is full! \n");
    } else {
        s->top++;
        s->st[s->top] = item;
    }
}

int pop(struct stack *s){
    if(s->top == -1){
        printf("Stack is empty! \n");
        return -1;
    } else {
        int item = s->st[s->top];
        s->top--;
        return item;
    }
}
```

Thank you for help @Fe203 and @Jabberwocky

Answer (score 2):

What you haven't grasped, it seems, is the *complementary* operations of **pre**increment and **post**decrement.
Alternatively, using base 0 (as below) the operations are **post**increment and **pre**decrement...

Also, there's no need to *fiddle* with negative numbers! Array indices are positive numbers...

Having been asked to help out, here is the code revised to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 10

typedef struct {
    int st[SIZE];
    size_t cnt; // Notice the change
} stack;

// Functions defined ahead of their use are their own prototypes. Saves typing.

void push( stack *s, int item ) {
    if( s->cnt == SIZE )
        printf("Stack is full! \n");
    else
        s->st[ s->cnt++ ] = item; // post increment!! 0->1->2...8->9  10==FULL
}

int pop( stack *s ) {
    int rval = 9999; // something to return

    if( !s->cnt )
        printf("Stack is empty! \n");
    else
        rval = s->st[ --s->cnt ]; // pre decrement!!

    return rval;
}

void peep( stack *s ) {
    if( !s->cnt )
        printf("Stack is empty! \n");
    else
        printf("Top item in the stack: %d \n", s->st[ s->cnt - 1 ] );
        // This is the ONLY time in code that one has to fiddle (-1) the counter...
}

int main( void ) {
    int var;

    stack s = { 0 }; // The stack is initialised

    label:

    printf(
        "Enter the operation you want to perform: \n"
        " 1. Push \n"
        " 2. Pop \n"
        " 3. Peep \n"
        " 4. Exit \n");

    scanf( "%d", &var ); // Add checking of return value!

    switch( var ) {
        case 1:
            printf("Enter the element you want to push: ");
            scanf( "%d", &var ); // Check here too. User input is nasty!!
            push( &s, var );
            goto label;

        case 2:
            printf( "Popped item: %d\n", pop(&s) );
            goto label;

        case 3:
            peep( &s );
            goto label;

        case 4:
            break;

        default:
            printf("Please enter the valid option!");
            goto label;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank You! but it's stack and the initial value of top is supposed to be initialized with -1. I did some changes in the push and pop operations and it's working fine now. You can check my answer.

Comment: If you've found any of the offered answers solve your issue, it is customary to ACCEPT that which best answers your problem.

Comment: `goto label`? Why not a loop?

Comment: @Haris The OP had trouble with the stack indexing... "Sufficient unto the day"... :-) (The OP even thinks they should instruct the person providing the answers that "top to be initialised with -1."... Go figure, eh? :-)